# Getting ID from json data

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js, marionette, esri

Forgive me if my verbiage is off but I'm just learning GIS stuff.  I'm making an ajax call to a mapping server and in my firebug console, this is exactly what I'm seeing.

```
jQuery19008239585978290092_1392763042662({
    "displayFieldName" : "name",
    "fieldAliases" : {
    "ID" : "ID",
    "name" : "name"
    },
    "geometryType" : "esriGeometryPoint",
    "spatialReference" : {
    "wkid" : 102100
    },
    "fields" : [
        {
          "name" : "ID",
          "type" : "esriFieldTypeInteger",
          "alias" : "ID"
        },
        {
          "name" : "name",
          "type" : "esriFieldTypeString",
          "alias" : "name",
          "length" : 150
        }
    ],
    "features" : [{
        "attributes" : {
            "ID" : 114,
            "name" : "LewisGale Hospital - Pulaski"
          },
        "geometry" : {
            "x" : -8989914.6998432986,
            "y" : 4448752.1187390834
          }
    }
  ]
});
```

the ajax calls I'm used to working with do not have the jQuery19008239585978290092_1392763042662 part of it so I'm not sure how to deal with that part of the data.

Below is my success statement:

```
success: function (json) {
    console.log(json);
},
```

which is not returning anything which normally would.  I think the jQuery19008239585978290092_1392763042662 is throwing me off and I dont know how to deal with the json object or how to traverse it in this format.  All I need form this data set is the ID value which in this case is 114.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your log output is that of a function call. The function in question is named `jQuery19008239585978290092_1392763042662()`, and it's taking a single argument: an anonymous object that looks like the payload of your response.

I suppose it's possible that you're getting odd behavior from Firebug's logging; jQuery runs JSON responses through `$.parseJSON()` before returning it. Try simply logging the ID in the success handler: `console.log('id=', json.features[0].attributes.ID);`

It's also possible you're using something other than `$.ajax` or `$.get` method with a `dataType` of `json`, or `$.getJSON`. If so, you may have to more explicitly specify the data types and/or `accepts` values in your AJAX call.

Comment: the datatype is jsonp - I didn't catch that earlier.  Let me try your console.log to see what I get as an output.

Comment: Nothing is showing up with the console.log statement, even if I use `console.log(json);`  I failed to address your $.ajax comment - it is a jQuery ajax call most definitely.

Comment: If the datatype is `jsonp`, then jQuery is trying to evaluate it as a callback. You probably need a `jsonpCallback`. See the JSONP discussion at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Can you tell me how do I know when I need a [0] as in `json.features[0].attributes.ID)` ?  Also, if the `[0]` is required, will it always be a `[0]` or could it be another number such a s `[3]` ?

Comment: It could always be another number. The reason I specified `[0]` is because your problem asked for the ID with the value of 114. That is the ID of the first element of the `features` array. Unfortunately, not knowing the API nor your requirements, it's difficult to suggest a different solution, but the general case is that you will have to figure out which element of `features` contains the data you're looking for. It may be that you can iterate over each element and compare IDs or some other attribute value.

Comment: So you just iterate the list (i know there is more to it than this but keeping it simple here) beginning at 0 and working up until you reach the "branch" containing the data you are looking for.